# Does a ROS node have to exist within a package?

Tags: ros, rosnode, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've gone through part of the ROS tutorial, and I'm still a bit confused on a very basic concept: does a ROS node have to exist within a ROS package? If I wanted to write the most basic "hello world" ROS program/node, do I need to build a whole ROS package around it, with a manifest.xml etc., or can I just include the proper ROS headers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61919/does-a-ros-node-have-to-exist-within-a-package?/) by [crunchytheory](https://answers.ros.org/users/4798/crunchytheory/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes. Every node should be in a package.

roscreate-pkg makes creating packages easy enough that this isn't be a big hassle.

Longer answer: C++ and python nodes need the package infrastructure to resolve their dependencies, particularly for rosmake packages. With the newer catkin build system in Groovy, it is possible to cheat and make a python node without a package, if it only depends on other catkin packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6